# How to implement vertical chaining with Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a **LinearLayout** which each view fills the space proportional to their weight value.

I have a fragment of `layout_weight` 8 and a TextView of `layout_weight` 2.

This is the Image Below:

[image: Linear Weight Image]

With this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text \nof the printing and typesetting industry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now After converting this into **ConstraintLayout**, I find it hard to replicate this by define weighted layouts with constraint chains.

The Fragment fills the screen and the TextView is on top of it, Instead of just taking the specified space of `layout_constraintVertical_weight` = 8 and `layout_constraintVertical_weight` = 2 respectively.

This is the Image Below:

[image]

With this code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text \nof the printing and typesetting industry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

According to the documentation, It says `using the layout_constraintHorizontal_weight and layout_constraintVertical_weight attributes. If you're familiar with layout_weight in a linear layout, this works the same way.` It's not working for me, or maybe I am implementing in the wrong way.

**How can I convert my LinearLayout to Constraint Layout properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For fragment you are using wrong bottom constraint. fragment bottom constraint should be top of textview.

Also, you don't need to use layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text \nof the printing and typesetting industry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> 2nd way -> Also, you can do it without weight. Without layout_constraintVertical_weight you can do using guidline.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text \nof the printing and typesetting industry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For chaining the views you need to bound them one to another. In your xml you need to change the fragment `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"` and add `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"` to TextView.

Also, I've changed `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"` for both fragment and TextView as it is correct to use `0dp` for spreading the views between the constraints.

**Here is the solution.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text \nof the printing and typesetting industry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```